# Error Using Qt 5.3.1 with Open Inventor 9.4.1 with visual2013: C2371:"GLdouble redefinition"

Tags: c++, qt, openinventor

I'm programming using Open Inventor, I've included SoQt.h.

When I complile a simple code, an error occour:

C:\Open Inventor\9.4.1 C++ Visual2013 x64\include\Inventor\sys\SoGLType.h:39: error: C2371: 'GLdouble': redefinition. different basic types.
......\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui/qopengl.h(98): see declaration of 'GLdouble'

I'm using Open Inventor 9.4.1 Qt 5.3.1 on Qt creator 3.2.0. I compile with VIsual C++ compiler 12.0 (x86) on Windows 7

Comment: `A simple code`, what code? We're not wizards that can read through the magic of Internet. Provide your code please :)

Comment: http://oivdoc94.vsg3d.com/content/184-qt

it's a demostration code to use qt and open inventor

Comment: BTW searching this error alone has a few hits on google and seems to be Qt related: ***'GLdouble': redefinition. different basic types***

Comment: Yes. I've searched on google. But nothing usefull.

Comment: Did you recompile Qt? The reports from many libraries seem to suggest you need to build Qt with a switch enabled for opengl.

Comment: Here is what I see in several threads ***In short: for Visual Studio is to use/build Qt and disable angle (-no-angle) AND use -opengl desktop.***

Comment: I think I've understood: this is a compatibility problem between Qt 5 and Open Inventor 9. My new goal is to use qt 4.8 on qt creator, but it seems to be impossible.

Comment: To solve the problem:

- download qt 4.8.6
- compile qt 4.8.6 with your compiler 
- in qt creator set a new kit with qt 4.8.6

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Qt 5.x is not supported by Open Inventor 9.4.x
You will have some support in the next incoming version Open Inventor 9.5.x
Ask to official support for more details.